# how to constraintlayiut and include?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e45aN.jpg)I want to put the processbar under the id iv_logo, but the progressbar is located at the top center, how can I do that?

Additionally, I am using databinding. Please let me know if there is any problem here.

```css
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_logo" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

```html
       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_alogo"
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_pnt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: iv_log or tv_logo?

Comment: i add photo please check it

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to rethink your layout structure completely.

In addition, your iv_alogo has no vertical constraints, so it is not known exactly where it will be placed on the layout.

I offer you two options here:

1. Refuse include and place two AppCompatImageView in the main layout.
2. Place the progress bar inside the included layout.

In this case, it is not clear why you using include here.

Answer (score 0):

your XML attribute is pointing on some `View` with `tv_logo` id

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_logo"
```

but in second XML snippet (assuming part of `@layout/activity_start`) there is no `View` with such id... maybe try with one of these ids, which are placed in `activity_start` layout, so `iv_logo` or `iv_alogo`?

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_logo"
//or
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_alogo"
```

edit: due to posted image - it looks like you are looking for centering, not placing below another `View`. for centering use

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: I wanted to place it under the id in include, but is that impossible? Am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` takes `id` as reference, so your `<include` tag should have own `id`. but I doubt it will work with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for `<include`, worth trying with `wrap_content` set for it

Comment: this may not work as `id` attr set for `include` tag just overrides `id` of root `View` of included layout. if you are using `<merge` tag in there - there is nothing to override... then you have to stick with `ImageView`s `id`s

Comment: i add photo please check it

Comment: edited my answer. btw. have you tried first approach? (`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_logo"` line)